# Laravel socialite error 404

Tags: laravel, authentication, http-status-code-404

I followed this tutorial on how to use socialite -> https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/9

This is what I've done:

- Added to my *composer.json*

  `"laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
   "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*@dev"`
- Added to my *app.php*

  *providers*

  `Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
   Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,`

  *aliases*

  `'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
   'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
   'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,`
- Added to *services.php*

`'github' => [
        'client_id' => 'myid',
        'client_secret' => 'mysecret',
        'redirect' => 'http://inspectorhost.app/login',
    ],`

- Added to *routes.php*

  ```
   Route::get('/', function () {
     if (Auth::check()) return 'Welcome back, ' . Auth::user()->username;

    return 'Hi guest. ' . link_to('login', 'Login with Github!');
       });

    Route::get('login', 'AuthController@login');
  ```
- Created an *AuthController* and added

  `class AuthController extends Controller
  {
      public function login(){
          return \Socialite::with('github')->redirect();
      }
  }`

I'm using nginx and I set it up so it doesn't need to use the *public folder* to acccess the web

```
   root home/inspectorhost.app/public_html/public/;
```

So when I click on 'Login with Github', instead of sending me to Github to authorize the login, it sends me to /login and gives me a 404 error.

**EDIT**
Now it gets interesting... when I go to http://inspectorhost.app and click in 'Login with Github' I get the error from above (404) however if I run *php artisan serve* and I access the app from localhost:8000 it works... so I guess it might be some misconfiguration on nginx?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check the logs to see if there is an error. If you [download the code from github](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-OAuth-and-Socialite) and run it, do you get the same error?

Comment: @Jeemusu Well, I tried to use the code from github but it uses an older version of socialite and laravel and even trying to run that code ends giving an error Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Application::detectEnvironment() must be an instance of Closure, array given,

Comment: Well, it will be hard to help without seeing your specific code. Post your html link, your route declarations, and your controller method, and someone should be able to help you.

Comment: @Jeemusu You're right, it was quite late and just posted before falling asleep. I updated the post with everything I did, code included. Btw, the logs don't show any errors.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like your nginx config isn't set up properly. I would post your configts `server {}` section.

Answer (score 0):

Open in private window. because after first time session store in github if your github login in other tab

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).